# How can i create a common control in Angular 2/4?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have to create a control/template/common html which will have a drop down. This common control will call my data service and bind this drop down with data.

I can create a component and have it's HTML as drop down and call the selector of the component in all my parent component. But, what I want is I need to pass key to this common control and this key will be sent to service and service will give only matching record and as per these records Dropdown will get bind.

Here what my pseudo code code is :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Forms</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option value="Expression">Expression</option>
                <option value="Tender">Tender</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Instead of this i want something like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Forms</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
             COMMONCONTROL('KEY')
            </div>
          </div>
```

What is the way to achieve this in angular 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just create a component which implements the [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface and then connect it with the `ngModel` of the select element. For better usage i would suggest to implement an abstract class first:

```
import { Provider, forwardRef, Type, OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

export abstract class AbstractValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private _value: any = null;
    public onChange = (_) => { };
    public onTouched = () => { };

    public get value(): any {
      return this._value;
    }

    public set value(v: any) {
      if (v !== this._value) {
        this._value = v;
        this.onChange(v);
      }
    }

    public writeValue(value: any) {
      this._value = value;
      this.onChange(value);
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
      this.onChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
      this.onTouched = fn;
    }
}

export function MakeProvider(type: any) {
  return {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => type),
    multi: true
  };
}
```

More information about how an implemented value accessor looks like and works can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/DefaultValueAccessor). For info about the various accessor implmentations in angular look [here](https://angular.io/api?query=ValueAccessor).

And then extend your component with it:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { AbstractValueAccessor, MakeProvider } from './abstract-value-accessor';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-select',
    templateUrl: './custom-select.component.html',
    providers: [MakeProvider(CustomSelectComponent)],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CustomSelectComponent extends AbstractValueAccessor implements OnChanges {
    private data$$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

    @Input()
    public dataKey: string;

    public data$ = this.data$$.asObservable();

    public get hasData$() {
        return this.data$.map(data => data.length > 0);
    }

    constructor(private dataService: MyDataService) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if(changes.dataKey && changes.dataKey.currentValue) {
           this.getData(changes.dataKey.currentValue);
        }
    }

    private getData(dataKey: string) {
        this.dataService.get(dataKey).take(1).subscribe(data => this.data$$.next(data));
    }
}
```

And in your component's template you bind it to the select:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="value" *ngIf="hasData$ | async">
    <option [value]="option.value" *ngFor="let option of data$ | async">{{ option.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Then you can use it where ever you want like:

```
<custom-select dataKey="test"></custom-select>
```

Note: This code is untested and only offers a way in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks man for fast reply. This what i was looking for. one more query how to get selected item from this custom control? should i access value property you mentioned in template?

Comment: To access the currently selected value you could either use `reactive-forms` via `FormControl` as usual or bind to `ngModel` like `<custom-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"></custom-select>`.

Comment: great!! and thank you so much. It will be really helpful for me and anybody who is looking for such problem. I will check it and set as answer.

Comment: It is working. Now i have one more query . Why do we have to create abstract class when we can create a child component and pass input value to it?

Comment: The abstract class is there because you propaply want to have more custom components which can be used as a form control. It's just bundling the needed implementation to make a value accessor work. You could put all of the code of the abstract class into the component's code.