# Wraping components in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design

I need to wrap a mat-slide-toggle component on my own, I wrote:

**mytoggle.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, forwardRef, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {MatSlideToggle, MatSlideToggleChange} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng7-common-ng7-slide',
  templateUrl: 'ng7-slide.component.html',
  styles: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => Ng7SlideComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class Ng7SlideComponent extends MatSlideToggle {

}
```

And **mytoggle.component.html**:

```
<mat-slide-toggle
    [checked]="checked"
    [disabled]="disabled">
    {{label}}
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

and in my app I'm using like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(formGroup.value)" ngNativeValidate>


  <!-- THIS WORKS <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="slideToggle">Enable Wifi</mat-slide-toggle> -->
  <ng7-common-ng7-slide formControlName="slideToggle" label="test me!">
</ng7-common-ng7-slide>

  <button mat-rasied-button type="submit">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSlideToggleChange } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
      slideToggle: false
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit(formValue: any) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 2));
  }

}
```

So the formValue on onFormSubmit method always alerts "slideToggle":false no matter is it is checked or not, when I use mat-slide-toggle it alerts true or false according with the toggle state correctly.

Are there anything else to do? I just need to extend the component and all event.

Comment: Just wrapping a material component inside your component will not bind all the events from material component to your component. If you want to achieve that you can try input output modifiers, eventemitter to bind the events.

Comment: Could you give me an example ?

Comment: Why not just including a mat-slide-toggle on your components template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I got something that works well..

I imported an abstract class that implements the basic value acessors methods:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480791/2161180

```
import { ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

export abstract class AbstractValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    innerValue: any = '';
    get value(): any { return this.innerValue; }
    set value(v: any) {
      if (v !== this.innerValue) {
        this.innerValue = v;
        this.onChange(v);
      }
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
      this.innerValue = value;
      this.onChange(value);
    }

    onChange = (_) => {};
    onTouched = () => {};
    registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

Then I created my component extending it:

```
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractValueAccessor } from '../abstract.component';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-switch',
      templateUrl: './my-switch.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./my-switch.component.css'],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          multi: true,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => MySwitchComponent)
        }
      ]
    })
    export class MySwitchComponent extends AbstractValueAccessor {

      @Input() label: string;
      @Input() checked: boolean;
      @Input() disabled: boolean;

    }
```

html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    [checked]="checked"
    [disabled]="disabled">
  {{label}}
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

module:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MySwitchComponent } from './my-switch.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MySwitchComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MySwitchComponent
  ]
})
export class MySwitchModule { }
```

And to use it:

```
<form [formGroup]="fb">
  <my-switch formControlName="inputSwitch" label="Toggle-me!"></my-switch> 
  <strong> Value: </strong> {{inputSwitch}}
</form>
```

or

```
<my-switch [(ngModel)]="inputSwitchNgModel" label="Toggle-me!"></my-switch>
<strong> Value: </strong> {{inputSwitchNgModel}}
```